# Django: Redirect from FormView to DetailsView upon submitting the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Relevant FormView:

```
class addrecipe(FormView):
    form_class = AddRecipeForm
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipebook/addrecipe.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_context = {
        'recipe_list': Recipe.objects.all()
    }
```

Relevant Form:

```
    class AddRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(max_length="50", label="Recipe Name")
        description = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'desc-text-area'})
        servings = forms.IntegerField()
        tools = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tool.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = True, help_text="Select all relevant tools")

        class Meta:
            model = Recipe
            fields = ("__all__")
```

URL pattern for the details view page:

```
    path('<int:pk>/recipedetails', views.recipedetails.as_view(), name='recipe_details'),
```

**I want to have the user submit the form, then be taken to the details page of the entry they just made into the database.** I've tried doing this using reverse/reverse_lazy with a success url but that hasn't been successful.

I also tried adding the following to my form view class:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    test_recipe_id = self.object.id
    return reverse('recipeBook:recipe_details', pk=test_recipe_id)
```

After also changing my path to:

```
re_path(r'(?P<pk>[^/]+)/recipedetails', views.recipedetails.as_view(), name='recipe_details'),
```

I get the following Value error:

```
AttributeError at /recipebook/addrecipe
'addrecipe' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use HttpResponseRedirect to redirect correctly. My view ended up looking like this:

```
class addrecipe(FormView):
    form_class = AddRecipeForm
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipebook/addrecipe.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_context = {
        'recipe_list': Recipe.objects.all()
    }
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        test_recipe = form.save(commit=False)
        test_recipe.save()
        test_recipe_id = test_recipe.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('recipeBook:recipe_details', kwargs={'pk': test_recipe_id}))
```

Saving the object before grabbing the ID appears to be a necessary step as I found that the ID itself is only created when the object is created.

The reverse return wasn't working, so honestly I hail mary'd a httpresponseredirect in front and it worked. I will update the answer if I figure out why..

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was almost there.
You could use the `get_success_url` method to get the recipe ID after the model. This will allow you redirect with parameters.

```py
class addrecipe(FormView):
    form_class = AddRecipeForm
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipebook/addrecipe.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_context = {
        'recipe_list': Recipe.objects.all()
    }
    
    #New method
    def get_success_url(self):
        test_recipe_id = self.object.id #gets id from created object
        return reverse('recipeBook:recipe_details', pk=test_recipe_id)
```

Your `detail url` is not receiving the parameter as expected hence it needs to be reconfigured with a new regex
**Old:**

```
path('<int:pk>/recipedetails', views.recipedetails.as_view(), name='recipe_details'),
```

**New:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

re_path(r'(?P<pk>[^/]+)/recipedetails', views.recipedetails.as_view(), name='recipe_details),
```

Comment: Writing this out, I'm met with the error "NoReverseMatch at /recipebook/addrecipe
Reverse for 'recipe_details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 'test_recipe_id'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['recipebook/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/recipedetails\\Z']"

I've edited the post to reflect my solution (basically yours with a few differences).

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect your question

Comment: Seems like we are getting closer, but I'm now getting the following value error "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.".

Comment: looks like the url is not receiving the id on `test_recipe_id = test_recipe.id`. We'll have to use the `get_success_url()` method

Comment: Would that be in place of the form_valid definition? Could you edit the answer to reflect that? Would be appreciated.

Comment: since we'll be using the `get_success_url` to get the id, there'll be no use for the `form_valid` method. Model form views provide a form_valid() implementation that saves the model automatically. let me edit the answer

Comment: I have added in the solution, but I'm now met with "AttributeError at /recipebook/addrecipe
'addrecipe' object has no attribute 'object'". Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, sorry but we need to take a step back and to the previous solution. Try printing the id in `form_valid` and see what it gives you `test_recipe_id = test_recipe.id` > `print(test_recipe_id)`. I know that solution was right

Comment: The test_recipe appears to be saving correctly, as if I print test_recipe itself, it returns the name of the object, but printing test_recipe_id returns "None"

The data is definitely getting added to the database with id's.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I managed to fix it, we were just missing one step!

Comment: Oh wow nice, I was recreating that on my machine. Could you show how you did it for future reference?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check stack on my days off. I added the solution to an answer, but I'm not convinced that it's the best way to do it (but it works...)